# Sort criteria in views: how to add custom one

Tags: 7, views

I have added a "node title" field.  I want to add this sort criteria to the node: the number of times the node  has been viewed by visitors in a week, descending.
If I want to add a sort criteria with PHP code and a SQL query to insert in Views module, how should I do?

**ps:i have overwritten a field. i want to query the database and using the query to Sort Criteria**how to add the custom one**

Comment: You don't alter the code of Views to add a new sort criteria: you create a module that implements the new criteria. Are you sure there isn't already a similar sort criteria?

Comment: yeah.i am sure,if i create a module that implements the new criteria.how do i do?

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you have Drupal's **Statistics** module enabled and collecting page view statistics.

In Drupal 6, you need to enable **Count content views** under `admin/reports/settings`. This will count total node views and give you total day count. Unfortunately, it does not give you a weekly view count by default.

This will give you a sort criteria for `Node statistics: Total views` and `Node statistics: Views today`.

Upon closer inspection of the day count for node views, this value is reset to 0 every 24 hours by `statistics_cron`. This value would prove more useful as a sort criteria if it was the *most recent 24 hour's* node views. So, the `Node statistics: Total views` would be your best bet.

**NOTE:** See [Statistics Granularity](http://drupal.org/project/statistics_granularity) module for week, month and year.

Comment: thank you..if i want to add a Sort criteria to views. do you know how to add it?

Comment: Yes. Edit the view. There's a section called "Sort Criteria". You will find the relevant sorting criteria under "Node statistics". You might also want to install the [Advanced Help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module to read Views documentation.

Comment: thank you, i know that. but i have overwrote a field. i want to query the database and using the query to Sort Criteria